# Funding to do PhD

Tags: funding

What is the possibility for an international student to do a PhD in Monash Australia without a scholarship? Scholarship application to the university was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking about procedures at a single university are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Some supervisors have their own funding. A candidate should usually have a first class and a few publications in order to get a general scholarship as per my knowledge. However, if your supervisor has some funding and he is willing to support you, you can have a chance. Otherwise you can increase your qualifications and apply in the next round. I know some students who could not get selected for Monash funding but have received scholarships from UNSW. Another option is getting permanent residency (PR visa). In that way government pays all your tuition fees. But you need to find a way to cover your living expenses (one option-you can work as a teaching associate).

Answer (score 0):

There are certain funding schemes like Endeavour Australia that might be available to you, potentially. Perhaps depending on your topic, the relevant government department may have some additional scholarships available (either in your own country or in Australia). There may be various country specific programs available to you too, for example the Chinese Academic of Sciences (CAS) has a program. **Expect all of these options to be very competitive.**

Comment: Hi jdpipe, thanks for your reply. I am aware of Endeavour Australia and would like to know other possibilities.

Comment: ANU has a search system, http://www.anu.edu.au/students/scholarships-support. In several cases the listed scholarships are not specific to ANU. Maybe Monash has something similar.